# How to correctly call for `Mage.php` in the root folder

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to access store config from Magento root folder.

If the file is in the root folder I can do this by: `require_once(__DIR__ . '/app/Mage.php');`

Although, if I would have my file in, for example `*root folder*/Jurgis/Twilio/file.php`
 I get an error `No such file or directory`,
how do I then properly call the `Mage.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require_once('./../../app/Mage.php');
```

Comment: This is a more elegant approach than what I came up with.

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer:

`require_once (dirname(dirname(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)))).'/app/Mage.php');`